# Windows-Terminal Theme Colors SSH

Tags: ssh, themes, windows-terminal

I am running Ubuntu-20.04 in WSL 2 and use Windows Terminal. I am using the colorScheme "Dracula" and in my local bash everything is displayed perfectly. But as soon as I SSH into a remote machine the default colors are displayed. This makes for example directories very hard to read.

[image: local bash on the left side, ssh into remote server on right side]

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. The problem was not the color scheme but that the dircolors were not set. I added the following to my .bashrc file:

```
eval `dircolors`
```

This fixed it for me.